# How to include files in Tweak.xm from subproject library in Theos

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos, tweak

I've created a simple tweak using [Theos](https://github.com/theos/theos). Then, also using Theos templates I created a library in my tweak, and it was automatically added as a subproject, exactly as I need, in my tweak's Makefile were added the following two lines:

```
SUBPROJECTS += alertlib
include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/aggregate.mk
```

The question is: how can I include/access files from newly created library in `Tweak.xm` file? Tried to import, but without success, I'm receiving `Undefined symbols for architecture armv7` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TWEAKNAME_FILES=Tweak.xm YOURNEWCODE

Example:

```
include $(THEOS)/makefiles/common.mk

TWEAK_NAME = Kit
Kit_FILES = Tweak.xm SomeClass.mm
include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk  
BLAH BLAH
```